# What are some ways to maintain data consistency at the application layer of NoSQL?

Tags: python, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

My python web application uses DynamoDB as its datastore, but this is probably applicable to other NoSQL tables where index consistency is done at the application layer. I'm de-normalizing data and creating indicies in several tables to facilitate lookups.

For example, for my users table:

```
* Table 1: (user_id) email, employee_id, first name, last name, etc ...
  Table 2: (email) user_id
  Table 3: (employee_id) user_id
```

Table 1 is my "primary table" where user info is stored. If the user_id is known, all info about a user can be retrieved in a single GET query.

Table 2 and 3 enable lookups by email or employee_id, requiring a query to those tables first to get the user_id, then a second query to Table 1 to retrieve the rest of the information.

My concern is with the de-normalized data -- what is the best way to handle deletions from Table 1 to ensure the matching data gets deleted from Tables 2 + 3? Also ensuring inserts?

Right now my chain of events is something like:

```
1. Insert row in table 1
2. Insert row in table 2
3. Insert row in table 3
```

Does it make sense to add "checks" at the end? Some thing like:

```
4. Check that all 3 rows have been inserted.
5. If a row is missing, remove rows from all tables and raise an error.
```

Any other techniques?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you considered using a SQL database? This kind of data sounds much better suited to SQL than anything else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementation of Atomic Transactions in dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664966/implementation-of-atomic-transactions-in-dynamodb)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is: There is **no way to ensure consistency**. This is the price you agreed to pay when moving to **NoSQL** in trade of performances and scalability.

DynamoDB-mapper has a "**transaction engine**". Transaction objects are plain DynamoDB Items and may be persisted. This way, If a logical group of actions aka transaction has succeeded, we can be sure of it by looking at the persisted status. But we have no mean to be sure it has not...

To do a bit of advertisment :) , dynamodb-mapper transaction engine supports

- single/multiple targets
- sub transactions
- transaction creating objects (not released yet)

If you are rolling your own mapper (which is an enjoyable task), feel free to have a look at our source code: https://bitbucket.org/Ludia/dynamodb-mapper/src/52c75c5df921/dynamodb_mapper/transactions.py

Disclaimer: I am one of the main dynamodb-mapper project. Feel free to contribute :)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I haven't actually used DynamoDB, just looked through the data model and API, so take this for what it's worth.

The use case you're giving is one primary table for the data, with other tables for hand-rolled indices. This really sounds like work for an RDBMS (maybe with some sharding for growth). But, if that won't cut it, here a couple of ideas which may or may not work for you.

A. Leave it as it is. If you'll never serve data from your index tables, then maybe you can afford to have lazy deletion and insertion as long as you handle the primary table first. Say this happens:

```
1) Delete JDoe from Main table
xxxxxxxxxx Process running code crashes xxxxxxx
2) Delete from email index       // Never gets here
3) Delete from employee_id index // Never gets here
```

Well, if an "email" query comes in, you'll resolve the corresponding user_id from the index (now stale), but it won't show up on the main table. You know that something is wrong, so you can return a failure/error and clean up the indexes. In other words, you just live with some stale data and save yourself the trouble, cleaning it up as necessary. You'll have to figure out how much stale data to expect, and maybe write a script that does some housekeeping daily.

B. If you really want to simulate locks and transactions, you could consider using something like Apache Zookeeper, which is a distributed system for managing shared resources like locks. It'd be more work and overhead, but you could probably set it up to do what you want.