# all transactions fails in dynamodb when condition for one of the transaction fails

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Data in **products** table in **dynamoDB**.

```js
[
  {
    productId:123,
    quantity:50
  },
  {
    productId:4565,
    quantity:10
  }
  // more items
]
```

Now, a client can order one or more than one product at once. Now, suppose the client is ordering products `123 & 4565` with quantity `30 & 12` respectively.

The client can purchase product `123`, but he can not purchase product `4565` because it has less quantity than the client wants.

I am using `AWS docClient` and `dc.transactWrite()` method to achieve this. But, the problem with `transactWrite` is that, if one of the conditions fails then all transactions will fail.

[Implementation of Atomic Transactions in dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664966/implementation-of-atomic-transactions-in-dynamodb)

**ConditionExpression for `transactWrite`**

```js
// QN - quantity
// :val - entered by client
ConditionExpression: '#QN >= :val'
```

Basically, I want to update the product which has the available quantity and give some information about the transaction which has not enough quantity.

Is there any way to achieve this, or I have to manually called `documentClient.update()` for every product.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of using a transaction is to ensure if one fails, nothing is changed.

That's the very definition of "transaction" in a DB.

Seems like you should just use [BatchWriteItem()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html)

> The individual PutItem and DeleteItem operations specified in
> BatchWriteItem are atomic; however BatchWriteItem as a whole is not.
> If any requested operations fail because the table's provisioned
> throughput is exceeded or an internal processing failure occurs, the
> failed operations are returned in the UnprocessedItems response
> parameter.

Comment: But, it doesn't provide any way to update any attributes based on it's previous value in database.

Comment: I used multiple requests to update multiple items.