# How to exclude multiple properties from comparison and diff check objects efficiently in FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, integration-testing, fluent-assertions, .net-7.0

In [FluentAssertions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions/), I can compare the object graphs of two objects of the same type and exclude properties from the comparison.

```
order.Should().BeEquivalentTo(anotherOrder, options => 
    options.Excluding(o => o.Customer.Name))
           .Excluding(o => /* Add more properties */);
```

I can then manually assert the excluded properties to make sure they were different or have a specific value:

```
order.Customer.Name.Should().NotBe(anotherOrder.Customer.Name).Should().Be("John");
// assert other properties
```

Assuming the list of properties to exclude is fairly large, is there a more concise way of combining the above statements to do diff checks?

Comment: Why not make a dummy object with the properties in the second case, and then exclude all the original properties? It might help to explain with some example data.

Comment: I have a local DB running in Docker. I retrieve `order`, modify it in a service class, and fetch `anotherOrder` with the same PK. I need to make sure the service works as intended. The problem is there is a lot of repetitive typing that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Also, the service class does not modify the in-memory object `order` since it issues a transaction to the database with syntax that looks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/53548148/246392.

Comment: So is your underlying problem that you want to ensure that _all_ of a set of properties have changes, not just that _some_ or atleast one of them has changed?

Comment: It's the final `Should Be` expression that I'm having trouble reconciling, why can't that be in your initial check, there is no value in a `NotBe`, then `Should().Be` on the same value, the `NotBe` is redundant as it will always be superseded by the final `.Be`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key concept driving *FluentAssertions* is to reduce complex and repetitive comparison checking and validation messaging down simple expressions that can manage the comparison for you.

In the OP, the example shows excluding `Customer.Name` from the initial comparison and then is explicitly validating the same field that was originally excluded with a hint that multiple properties need to be both excluded from the first set and separately *included* in individual assertions.

This concept really goes against what *FluentAssertions* is designed to do for you. To save you the repetitive code you should construct the specific object to compare against with all the fields set, rather than individual assertions against literal values.

For instance, this [forked fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q3lNIS) demonstrates some of the different ways you can declare your assertions on a simple nested object graph. When there are multiple failed assertions you can see all the results in a single output:

```
var order = externalProcess.FetchOrder();
var expectedOrder = new Order {
        Id = 201,
        Date = new DateTime(2022,11,01),
        Customer = new Customer {
            Id = 46,
            Name= "Johnothan" 
        }
    };
order.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedOrder);
```

If the retrieved order does not match, then this will generate an exception message with a deep analysis of all the failed assertions:

```
FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionFailedException: Expected property root.Customer.Id to be 46, but found 22.
Expected property root.Customer.Name to be "Johnothan" with a length of 9, but "John" has a length of 4, differs near "n" (index 3).
```

If you wanted to exclude/include multiple specific properties from the assertion, then there are two forms of configuration you can use:

Inline *expression* based lambda options:

```
    order.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedOrder, options => 
            options.Excluding(o => o.Customer.Name)
                   .Excluding(o => o.Customer.Id)
        );
```

*Method* based options:

```
    order.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedOrder, options => 
        {
            options.Excluding(o => o.Customer.Name);
            ...
            options.Excluding(o => o.Customer.Id);
            return options;
        });
```

But you really shouldn't have *overly* complex assertion conditions. If your intent was to exclude *most* of the `Customer` properties, but not all, then you can exclude the whole `Customer` property, and selectively *include* the fields that you need:

```
    order.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedOrder, options => 
            options.Excluding(o => o.Customer)
                   .Including(o => o.Customer.Name)
        );
```

This style of complementing *include* and *exclude* allows you to reduce the number of individual properties that need to be configured, but it also allows you to skip intermediary object relationships.

Consider if `Customer` has a complex property called *Address* and we wanted to compare that the `Customer`.Address`matched but we want to exclude comparisons on the`Customer` object:

```
    order.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedOrder, options => 
            options.Excluding(o => o.Customer)
                   .Including(o => o.Customer.Address)
        );
```

That skips the intermediary `Customer` from the comparison. But what if `Order` also has an `Address` and we want to test that the `Order.Address` equals the `Customer`.`Address` in the comparison object, well this is where we can use separate assertions

```
    order.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedOrder, options => 
            options.Excluding(o => o.Customer)
        );
    order.Address.Should().BeEquivalentTo(order.Customer.Address);
```

> There is a concept of *mapping* but we can't easily use it here because the path depths are expected the be the same, mapping is designed to allow mapping between similar *typed* properties at the same level but with different names.

If it helps, this was the end of my fiddle from playing around with these options: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TSLOXg